# Change several files with specific file extension to another extension in a folder

Tags: ansible

In a folder containing files with different extensions (`*.rules` and `*.rules.yml`), I need to change the file extension based on certain condition:

1. `*.rules` => `*.rules.yml`, or
2. `*.rules.yml` => `*.rules`

In shell, I can do it as:

```
Case # 1
for file in ./*.rules; do mv "$file" "${file%.*}.rules.yml" ; done 
# from *.rules to *.rules.yml


Case # 2
for file in ./*.rules.yml ; do mv "$file" "${file%.*.*}.rules" ; done 
# from *.rules.yml to *.rules
```

Any idea in ansible to do the same thing?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: I presume you mean _besides_ using `shell:` and doing exactly those steps?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel Embarrassing, actually I cannot use shell in ansible to do it :(

Comment: as in you are prohibited by company policy, or you mean it doesn't execute in `shell:` correctly?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel Quite new to Ansible, the format issue made the shell not work as it in a terminal. For now I am thinking about other methods to achieve the same purpose including directly using the shell in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the difficulty you are having is with YAML quoting, you may experience better luck with the "pipe literal":

```
  tasks:
  - shell: |
      for i in *.rules; do
        /bin/mv -iv "$i" "`basename "$i" .rules`.rules.yml"
      done
  - shell: |
      for i in *.rules.yml; do
        /bin/mv -v "$i" "`basename "$i" .rules.yml`.rules"
      done
```

One will also notice that I used the more traditional `basename` rather than trying to do "crafty" variable expansion tricks, since with it should run with any posix shell.

Or if you are experiencing that your target system uses dash, or zsh, or ksh, or whatever, you can also be explicit in the shell you wish for ansible to use:

```
tasks:
- shell: echo "hello from bash"
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, Matthew L Daniel. It works quite well.

The final working solution would be enclosed as reference:

```
- name: Run in local to replace suffix in a folder
  hosts: 127.0.0.1 
  connection: local

  vars:
    - tmpRulePath: "rules"
    - version: "18.06" # change the version here to change the suffix from rules/rules.yml to rules.yml/rules
    - validSuffix: "rules.yml"
    - invalidSuffix: "rules"

  tasks:
  - name: Prepare the testing resources
    shell: mkdir -p {{ tmpRulePath }}; cd {{ tmpRulePath }}; touch 1.rules 2.rules 3.rules.yml 4.rules.yml; cd -; ls {{ tmpRulePath }};
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"

  - name: Check whether it's old or not
    shell: if [ {{ version }} \< '18.06' ]; then echo 'true'; else echo 'false'; fi
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "Is {{ version }} less than 18.06 {{ result.stdout }}"

  - name: Update validSuffix and invalidSuffix
    set_fact:
      validSuffix="rules"
      invalidSuffix="rules.yml"
    when: result.stdout == "true"

  - debug:
      msg: "validSuffix is {{ validSuffix }} while invalidSuffix {{ invalidSuffix }}"

  - name: Replace the invalid suffix with valid
    shell: |
      cd {{ tmpRulePath }};
      for i in *.{{ invalidSuffix }}; do
        /bin/mv -v "$i" "`basename "$i" .{{ invalidSuffix }}`.{{ validSuffix }}"
      done

  - name: Check the latest files
    shell: ls {{ tmpRulePath }}
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"

  - name: Clean up
    shell: rm -rf {{ tmpRulePath }}
```